# error when installing react-to-pdf package

Tags: reactjs, react-to-pdf

when i try to install react-to-pdf package using this command : **npm install react-to-pdf**
i get this errors :

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT 
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js.git
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

could someone tell me what the problem is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js.git,
```

In general this kind of errors "undefined .... " means you are not able to execute a command because you do not have the cli, in this case a git command.

How to solve? Install git.

Comment: hello i have installing git using this command **npm install 
--save npm-git-install** but still can't install react-to-pdf

Comment: are you using windows?

Comment: It's seems like npm still don't have access to it. https://gitforwindows.org/ install git for windows and make sure that the option for Path environment => Git from command line and third party is selected. Also reboot after instalation finishes.

Comment: thank you that's work now, just a question when i finish my application and move it to cpanel do i need to install git also in cpanel ?

Comment: when you finish your application, you have to use something like npm run build, that will create an optimized build located in a build folder. The result of that is what you are going to deploy